# Jquery .attr() not reading my "data-link" html value during onclick event

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet of jQuery code which I would like to add a new li element to my menu, and not have a href tag, but rather control the link through js.

Don't ask me why, I have my secret reasons :D

I am base64 encoding the link into a html attribute "data-link".

The onclick event should handle the redirect, but for some reason this line is failing

```
let encLink = jQuery(this).attr("data-link"); // returning undefined
```

This was working during development, but something has happened and now and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Any help appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

    const link = "https://www.google.com";
    const text = "Link to google";

    const encodedLink = btoa(link);

    const ulSelector = "#menu-top-nav";
    const mobileulSelector = ".mobile-only ul:first-child";

    const newliElement = `<li data-link="${encodedLink}" style="cursor:pointer" class="menu-item jshref"><a>${text}</a></li>`;

    let newLi = jQuery(ulSelector + " > li:first-child").after(newliElement);
    let newLimobile = jQuery(mobileulSelector + " > li:first-child").after(newliElement);

    jQuery(document).on("click", ".jshref", (evt) => {      
        let encLink = jQuery(this).attr("data-link");
        console.log("encLink = " + encLink);
        const href = atob(encLink); // !problem encLink is undefined
        //window.location.href = href;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery(evt.currentTarget)` instead using `jQuery(this)` because arrow function does not have a this or their own.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks - I knew it was going to be a context issue.